# Sudden module imports issues

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, python-3.6, importerror

I've encountered one peculiar issue I just can't understand.
I've been working on a code in PyCharm, using Python 3.6 (Windows 10) and I've imported few modules for that objective like so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import lxml
```

For few days now I've been coding having no problems, I've run my code several times to test it and everything been going well until suddenly, without changing anything in the interpreter or any other setting, the modules seem to generate a lot of import errors such as:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'get'
```

This is so weird, suddenly I can't run my code and all my work is halted.
I've been looking up the internet and saw that usually this happens if you call one of your files in a same name as a module (for example, naming my file bs4.py), I'm afraid this is not the case here, I made sure my file is named in a unique name which doesn't exist anywhere on said libraries.
I couldn't find any other solution for this.
Can anyone help me figure this one out?

Comment: have you tried  running your code on command line?

Comment: Why would running the code on command line change anything?@Macintosh_89

Comment: Running it from command line works, it doesn't generate this issue.
How could that be?

Comment: Make sure there's no custom `requests` module or package in your project. Also, try to disable options "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH" and "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" in the corresponding Run Configuration in PyCharm.